# Facebook "posted by" not showing who posted

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I have Facebook Fan page. There are 5 editors on this page who post news on it and I am the Admin.

I noticed today that the latest post does not show "posted by" and I don't know who are posted latest post on the page.  Is it possible for editors to disable "Posted by" and How can I find who posted page latest post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the editors on the page deactivated his account after he had posted some content.

This way Facebook did not show "Posted by deactivated users"